# Maya 2015- Custom Shelf Button is Missing Icon

Tags: icons, maya

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Maya or if its an issue on my end- any insight would be appreciated.

I've got a button on a custom shelf. No issues there, it launches the script when clicked, has an annotation and a label, and generally works fine. However, the icon I've selected for it won't appear on the shelf. Instead, I get this:

[image: Missing Icon]

Oddly enough, even after restarting Maya, the icon is visible in the Shelf Editor window:

[image: Visible Icon]

So Maya is fully aware of the icon's path (it's a built-in Maya icon after-all) and is capable of displaying it- it just doesn't want to display it on the shelf.

To make matters even crazier, the custom shelf is being created and filled via a plugin that my company uses. As the tech artist, its my job to maintain this shelf, and so the plugin uses a shelf .mel file located in a network drive location, so that the tool can propagate the shelf to all the users on the network. On EVERY other users' machines, the icons are visible. It's only on my machine that they are not. Because of this, I feel that the plugin is not causing the issue. Naturally, all factors need to be considered, so I'm open to the possibility that it could be a problem with the plugin, but it seems odd that my machine would be singled out to have the icons not load on.

The final crazy thing: If I launch Maya the regular way rather than using my company's custom Maya launcher, the icons will not appear 50% of the time, but WILL appear the other 50% of the time.  The same thing happens using the custom launcher. Sometimes, half of the buttons have their icons and half don't. It seems totally arbitrary whether Maya loads them or not. But every single time, the icons are visible in the Shelf Editor window.

I guess my question is: What could cause the icons to be visible in the Shelf Editor, but not on the shelf?

Answer (score 0):

After a fair bit of experimentation, I've discovered that Maya does not like using some of its native icons as shelf icons.

I was able to fix the issue by identifying icons that will load every time, and using those.

If you have a particular Maya icon you really like, I recommend locating its file path, copying the image, and putting it somewhere outside of the Maya directory. For me, putting some of the images on our network drive did the trick, and all users were able to see the icons.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to determine why Maya wouldn't allow certain images to be visible on the shelf, and only on certain machines at that. I suspect it has something to do with the directory in which Maya is installed, and the Maya environment paths. But if you ever run into this issue, there are at least the above workarounds.